# Restriction of probability measure

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose that $\Omega$ is a finite set and $\Pr$ is a probability measure on it. Let $A$ be a subset of $\Omega$. What is the correct notation for the "restriction" of $\Pr$ to $A$, i.e. what's the correct notation for the probability measure $\mu$ defined on $A$ such that for $\omega\in A$
$$ \mu(\omega) = \frac{\Pr(\omega)}{\sum_{\omega\in A}\Pr(\omega)}? $$

Comment: Yes. And $\mu(A)=1$. However, I would write $\mu(\{\omega\})$  .

Comment: @zoli Oh sorry, I made my question unclear. I meant: is there a standard way to call that measure? I.e. would you write $\Pr|_A$ instead of $\mu$, for example?

Comment: Why don't you call it conditional probability; $P(\{\omega\}|A)=\begin{cases}\text{your notation} \\ 0 \ \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$